# magento command failing, getting "killed"

Tags: memory, memory-limit

am using these commands but keep getting this at the end that it got killed

```
php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php -d memory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

is 4G memory not enough? how can i know how much memory is really needed?
it shows compilation is started but then i get something like this 254MibKilled

Answer (score 0):

It seems the actual value for memory_limit is less than youe value.

First check your server memory_limit vaule in php.ini. You can check this on your Cpanel with your server administrator or simply add ***phpinfo.php*** file in your Magento root folder with the below content:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

then in browser add the URL: **yourdomain.com/phpinfo.php**
You can check the actual **memory_limit** value there.

[image]

If it's not set to your desired amount, you can set the 2G value on cPanel or ask the server admins to do this and again check the phpinfo.php result to see the updated value.

By this, you won't need to use **-d memory_limit=2G** in your commands anymore and the issue should be fixed.

Comment: And don't forget to remove the phpinfo.php later.